When upgrading version 1.2.2 to 1.3.0 of Apache IoTDB, why did error reported when replacing the data directories?
When I try to upgrade Apache IoTDB from Version 1.2.2 to 1.3.0, I keep the config and data directories that stored all data. The installation directory also has been replaced. However, an error is still reported when starting the seed ConfigNode. The data directory that includes confignode data and datanode data is still 1.2.2 version. What should I pay attention to during the upgrade process additionally?

The problem you mentioned should be with the online upgrade of Apache IoTDB version 1.3.0, which should be fixed in the new 1.3.1 version of IoTDB.
